# How to get the name of all container in docker using docker py

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

I need to get the name of all running container from docker py. I tried using below command but it responded with container id.

```
self.client = docker.from_env()
running_container = self.client.containers.list()
```

container names:

```
[<Container: ac380a213d>, <Container: 0bdc8b7569>, <Container: c9e9123544>, <Container: 6aaec45e8c>, <Container: 1b2a3d3732>, <Container: 946ada8f21>, <Container: 821978ae2c>]
```

May I know how can I convert it into corresponding docker container names

Answer (score 6):

You can use `.name` attribute to get the `container` name from container object [refer the doc](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html)

```
[container.name for container in running_container]
```